# Argument with 'controller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have found similar question but not getting solution so i have post a question.
I have been implementing and displaying data from database in angular js, below is mu code.

### index.php file:

```
<header>
<script type='text/javascript' src='local-path/js/angular.min.js?ver=4.9.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='local-path/js/angular-route.min.js?ver=4.9.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='local-path/js/scripts.js?ver=4.9.5'></script>
</header>

<div ng-controller="mycontrollermenu">
            First Name: {{firstname}}
            </div>

<div ng-view></div>

<footer></footer>
```

### script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('wp',['ngRoute','  ']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider  
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : localized.partials + 'main.php',
        controller  :  'Main'
    })
    .when('/:slug', {
        templateUrl: localized.partials + 'content.html',
        controller: 'Content'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller('Main',function($scope, $http, $routeParams){    
    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/').success(function(res){                
        $scope.posts = res;     
    });

});

app.controller('Content',
        ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {                     
            $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug=' + $routeParams.slug).success(function(res){                                                
                $scope.post = res[0];
            });
        }
    ]
);


app.filter('removeHTMLTags', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
    };
});

app.controller('mycontrollermenu',function($scope){
    $scope.firstname = "Menu 1";        
});
```

I have added controller mycontrollermenu in to index and js file which is not working, and thow an error like
    "Argument 'mycontrollermenu' is not a function, got undefined"

can any one guide me what i have doen wrong in "mycontrollermenu" controller?

Comment: add `script.js` file reference on the page, after angularjs file references

Comment: @PankajParkar:  yes, i have added it, but nothing changed.

Comment: @RaphaMex:  it is in header in html tag ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new `.js` file like `MenuController.js` and add the same

```
app.controller('mycontrollermenu',function($scope){
$scope.firstname = "Menu 1";        
 });
```

and in your index.html add `<script type='text/javascript' src='MenuController.js'></script>`

Comment: yes, it is working...can you tell me why i need to seperate code ?

Comment: Would be lying if I tell you why, for me it's better to segment javascript into files each controller is a file, insted of having one big `app.js` with all of the controllers and more. Upvote if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions,

- `ng-app` needs to be there on the root element. Wrap your HTML like `<div ng-app="wp">...<div>`
- `localized` is a global variable? It is neither injected nor declared.
- There is an empty string in the module definition. Forgot to include a dependency?

  `var app = angular.module('wp',['ngRoute','  ']);`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/90upfphb/) I have a fiddle working with your code.

Comment: ng-app declared in html tag in header,yes, localized variable is global variable, i have removed empty string in module definition as well. but it is still not working.